# How to make an executable file run on all systems

Tags: python, operating-system, windows-10, exe, executable

I am asking this because it is not information that I could find on the internet. Can an executable file run on all systems? If not, then how to you make different executable files for different systems? I use auto-py-to-exe (but my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191062/the-exe-file-stops-working-after-being-run-for-a-while)) at the moment but am having trouble with cx-freeze ([Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101482/cx-freeze-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied) - it doesn't have any answers). I am not sure about py-installer (although by the looks of things auto-py-to-exe uses py-installer - **Possible Idiot Statement**). Can someone give me an answer with sources? I code in python - using windows 10.

Comment: What systems are you including in "all systems"? Do you include Linux, Android, MacOS, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'auto-py-to-exe' use 'PyInstaller'.

And 'PyInstaller' freezes (packages) Python applications into stand-alone executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX. But It doesn't support a cross compile. (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ)

If you want Mac executable file, you have to perform it under Mac system.